# Print text in <p> element under <div>

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I need print text in `<p>` element with `class='fs-s fw-light pl-4 pr-4'` for every hause on website. I try this way, but it start and end immediately.

```
import gspread
import requests
import datetime 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import timedelta

datetime.datetime.now()

#zaklad pro scraping webu
URL = 'https://www.mmreality.cz/nemovitosti/prodej/byty/praha-vychod/?query=bcw9DoAgDIbh2zgjiro4eQzCQBB%2FErUEigm3F3Ss69Ovr4HzhEsG1BiDkkyNdWU%2B0wb32xZYLaxeuy3J2S46HjhBvNCn9%2BYhupAfJSZnvwRnjHqtRiEo8zL%2FyTR53lFuMw%2BUReaeclfi%2FAE%3D'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

#Scraping
results = soup.find_all('id', attrs={'class':'cell xsmall-24 mb-4 grid-y pos-relative rounded pseudo-border pseudo-border-primary-lightest pseudo-border-on-hover-none pseudo-box-shadow-xlarge-on-hover medium-12 xlarge-8'}) 
for job_data in results:

    nemovitost = job_data.find('p', attrs={'class':'fs-s fw-light pl-4 pr-4'})
    nemovitost_final = nemovitost.text.strip()

    print(nemovitost_final)
```

I try this code with `for job_data in results` - for id, because it is a header of group elements I want to print. After element `<p>` I want to print `<strong class="block text-secondary fs-xxl pl-4 pr-4 mb-4">6 800 000 Kč</strong>` and others.

I try print text from this website: [www.mmreality.cz](https://www.mmreality.cz/nemovitosti/prodej/byty/praha-vychod/?query=bcw9DoAgDIbh2zgjiro4eQzCQBB%2FErUEigm3F3Ss69Ovr4HzhEsG1BiDkkyNdWU%2B0wb32xZYLaxeuy3J2S46HjhBvNCn9%2BYhupAfJSZnvwRnjHqtRiEo8zL%2FyTR53lFuMw%2BUReaeclfi%2FAE%3D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this example to get your data:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.mmreality.cz/nemovitosti/prodej/byty/praha-vychod/?query=bcw9DoAgDIbh2zgjiro4eQzCQBB%2FErUEigm3F3Ss69Ovr4HzhEsG1BiDkkyNdWU%2B0wb32xZYLaxeuy3J2S46HjhBvNCn9%2BYhupAfJSZnvwRnjHqtRiEo8zL%2FyTR53lFuMw%2BUReaeclfi%2FAE%3D"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for p in soup.select("p.fs-s.fw-light.pl-4.pr-4"):
    popis = p.get_text(strip=True, separator="\n")
    cena = p.find_previous("strong").get_text(strip=True)

    print(popis)
    print(cena)
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Polerady
Prodej, Byt 3+kk, 246 m², Polerady
6 800 000 Kč
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Partyzánská, Odolena Voda
Prodej, Byt 3+kk, 80 m², Odolena Voda, Partyzánská
5 149 000 Kč
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Na Vyhlídce, Škvorec
Prodej, Byt 5+kk, 508 m², Škvorec, Na Vyhlídce
11 645 000 Kč
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Lipová, Mukařov
Prodej, Byt 5+kk, 252 m², Mukařov, Lipová
10 140 000 Kč
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Kosatcová, Říčany, Radošovice
Prodej, Atypický byt, 279 m², Říčany, Kosatcová
14 000 000 Kč
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Rooseveltova, Říčany
Prodej, Byt 4+kk, 109 m², Říčany, Rooseveltova
5 750 000 Kč
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```